# Format date using XSL

Tags: xslt

I have an XSL file which I use to simplify [this](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/XmlView.aspx?data=yieldyear&year=2016) XML. The date is in this format: `2016-01-04T00:00:00` and I pull it in using this:

```
 <NEW_DATE><xsl:value-of select="doc:content/m:properties/d:NEW_DATE"/></NEW_DATE>
```

What I want to do is modify it to be in this format first: `2016-01-04`. This is so that once it is in my database, I can join it to another table with dates formatted in this way.

What am I doing wrong with the below?

```
<NEW_DATE>
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(doc:content/m:properties/d:NEW_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')"/>
</NEW_DATE>
```

The PHP file which calls the XSL is generating these errors:

```
XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xmlXPathCompOpEval: function format-date bound to undefined prefix ms
XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xmlXPathCompiledEval: 1 objects left on the stack.
XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): runtime error: file xxx
XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): XPath evaluation returned no result.
XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xmlXPathCompOpEval: function format-date bound to undefined prefix ms
XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xmlXPathCompiledEval: 1 objects left on the stack.
XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): XPath evaluation returned no result.
```

Comment: please state clearly what your current result is, what you assume to be wrong/undesirable with it, and what your expected/desired result is.

Comment: I believe the format should be `'yyyy-MM-dd'`. What is the result you are getting?

Comment: Seeing some errors which im currently trying to understand:

Comment: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xmlXPathCompOpEval: function format-date bound to undefined prefix ms

Comment: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xmlXPathCompiledEval: 1 objects left on the stack.

Comment: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): XPath evaluation returned no result.

Comment: Instead of using an extension function to format a dateTime, just use `substring-before()`... `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(doc:content/m:properties/d:NEW_DATE,'T')"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`ms:format-date()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an extension function available in Microsoft .NET Framework XSLT processor. Apparently your processor is different, so use a purely XSLT 1.0 expression instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(doc:content/m:properties/d:NEW_DATE, 'T')"/>
```

---

Even in Microsoft environment, you must declare the `ms:` prefix:

```
xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

before you can use the extension functions.